# Creating a Table with the days of the Month

Tags: javascript, java

I've several problems at the moment and I can't see to find the solution.

**I insert two dates and I have the list of month, year between them.**

I'm trying to make a table to with:

- Number of Day
- Name of Day

and be able to:

- select month/year from a combobox (this gives the amount of days in the month)
- if it's exists you can use pagination to go to the next month,etc...

[MY LAYOUT](https://i.gyazo.com/d7aaa61abfaf7e4c351b129aed012650.png)

First Problem:
I'm using Java to pass a List to JavaScript and [I get this in the combobox](https://i.gyazo.com/b733d9a99c3bf28da808f62186d6d63d.png):

The second problem is basically I cant do anything else without the combobox correct value.

```
        <%
        String initialDayEnd = session.getAttribute("initialSystemDate").toString();
        String finalDayEnd = session.getAttribute("finalSystemDate").toString();

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);

        Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            beginCalendar.setTime(format.parse(initialDayEnd));
            finishCalendar.setTime(format.parse(finalDayEnd));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> dateListMonthYear = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] dateSplitted;
        while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
            // add one month to date per loop
            String date = format.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(date);
            beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            dateSplitted = date.split("/");
            dateList.add(dateSplitted[0] + "/" + dateSplitted[1] + "/" + dateSplitted[2]);
            dateListMonthYear.add(dateSplitted[1] + "/" + dateSplitted[2]);

        }
    %>
    <input type="hidden" id="dates" value="<%=dateListMonthYear%>">

                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Day</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Day</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody class="dayTableBody">
                            <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var dates = $('#dates').val();
    console.log(dates);
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu" : dates
    });
});

var day, month, year;

$('.dates').change(DatesChanged);
DatesChanged();

function DatesChanged() {
    var date = $('.dates').val();
    var splitDate = date.split("/");
    day = splitDate[0];
    month = splitDate[1];
    year = splitDate[2];
    var maxDays = daysInMonth(month, year);
    CreateJSONArray(maxDays, date);
}

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function CreateJSONArray(maxDays, date) {

    var arr = [];
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
    var dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var d;

    for (var day = 1; day <= maxDays; day++) {

        d = new Date(date);

        arr.push({
            "dayNumber": day,
            "dayName": dayNames[d.getDay()],
            "monthName": monthNames[month - 1],
            "year": d.getYear() + 1900
        });
        date = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }

    DisplayTable(arr);
    console.log(arr);
}

function DisplayTable(data) {

    //heading
    document.getElementsByClassName("month-year")[0].innerHTML = data[0].monthName + ", " + data[0].year;

    //Table
    $('.dayTableBody').empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        data += '<tr align="center">';
        data += '<td>' + value.dayNumber + '<input type="hidden" name="dayNumber" value="' + value.dayNumber + '">' + '</td>';
        data += '<td>' + value.dayName + '</td>';
        //get amount of types of Clients
        var clientTypes = ["Individual","Corporation"];
        for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {
            data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfClients" type="number" value="0" name="amountOfClients-' + clientTypes[i] + '"  data-error="Please, insert a value"  required>' + '</td>'
            data +=  '<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
        }
        data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('.dayTableBody').append(data);

}
```

***Maybe there is a simpler way to make this?***

Comment: Help please I'm desperate

Comment: ***hello darkness my old friend...***

Comment: it looks like some loop is iterating over your date string. do a console.log(data); in your DisplayTable() function and have a look at the output

Comment: Issues with your Question

 - You are likely asking too much in a single Stack Overflow question. Narrow to a single issue with stripped-down minimal code.

 - You are using troublesome old date-time classes that have been legacy for years now, supplanted by the java.time classes. In particular, you should be using `LocalDate` for date-only values.

 - You are using some localized format for exchanging date values as text, when you should ideally be using standard ISO 8601 strings. - You are raising issues handled many times already in existing Questions and Answers.